# Prevent windows from connecting to wireless when on cabled network?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, lan

At the office, I have a cabled LAN connection, and there are several WiFi networks. Often, Windows connects to a wireless network with a poor signal even though I'm plugged into the LAN by cable, resulting in a poor connection.

How can I prevent windows 7 from connecting to wireless network when I already have a LAN connection through cable?

Comment: Disable your wireless connection?

Answer (score 1):

There is a good manual by [itechtics.com](https://www.itechtics.com/5-ways-automatically-turn-off-wifi-ethernet-lan-cable-connected/) on how to set things straight there. They suggest one of the following approaches:

1. Configure *Network Adapter Settings*, if your wireless adapter allows it. To do that, go to the *Advanced* tab and enable the option "Disable Upon Wired Connect".
2. Use [*WLAN Manager* from Microsoft Technet](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/WLAN-Manager-f438a4d7).
3. Set *Network Adapters Priority* in the advanced settings of "change adapter settings".
4. Use the third party tool like [WirelessAutoSwitch](http://www.wirelessautoswitch.com/Downloads.aspx) or [BridgeChecker](https://store.accessagility.com/collections/trial) - don't ask me why you should pay for something you can get for free, though.

Comment: Thanks! "Disable upon wired connect" wasn't available, so I changed the network adapter prioritization.

Comment: Did it not work that way or why would you 'unmark' the answer as not solving the issue?

Comment: Sorry, I was going to add a comment but got sidetracked. No, unfortunately it still connect to the wireless network sometimes (the signal is pretty poor, so it might just be that the signal wasn't good enough to connect before, when I thought the problem was fixed). I will try the WLAN manager too, but I haven't gotten around to it yet.

Comment: I see. Sounds annoying. The WLAN Manager's description sounds quite promising for your purpose though: "_WLAN Manager runs as a scheduled task and will automatically disable your WLAN card when a LAN connection is verified. The WLAN card will be re-enabled once the LAN connection is lost. This ensures you'll have the fastest available connection and helps prevent network bridging._"